# CLLocationManager: didChangeAuthorization and didRangeBeacons is not getting called

Tags: swift, frameworks, core-location, ibeacon

I am developing a framework which has all the logic for beacon ranging and monitoring.

All the callbacks of `CLLocationManager` doesn't work. This only happens when I use the framework. If I transfer all the logic to the test app, it works.

Here are parts of the code:

This is the main class of the framework (which is called from the test app):

```
//Test App
let miniK = Kanban()
miniK.startBeaconSearch(forApiKey: "apikeytest", userID: "1")
```

```
public class Kanban: NSObject {


    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    public func startBeaconSearch(forApiKey apikey: String, userID: String){
        let beaconController = BeaconController.init(apikey: apikey, userId: userID)
        beaconController.startScanning()
    }

}
```

**BeaconController:**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import CoreBluetooth

class BeaconController : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var apiKey: String!
    var userID: String!
    var beaconsJson : [BeaconItem]?

    public override init(){
        super.init()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    public init(apikey:String, userId:String){
        super.init()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        apiKey = apikey
        userID = userId
        self.loadBeacons()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
    {
        if status == .authorizedAlways
        {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self){
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print("didRangeBeacons")
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            self.beaconReached(uuid: beacons[0].proximityUUID, minor: beacons[0].minor, major: beacons[0].major)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, rangingBeaconsDidFailFor region: CLBeaconRegion, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func startScanning() {
        print("StartScanning")
        sleep(5)
        //let beacon = beaconsJson![0]

        for beacon in beaconsJson! {
            print(beacon.BeaconUUID)
            let identifier = "iBeacon" + beacon.BeaconMajor.description + beacon.BeaconMinor.description
            let uuid = UUID(uuidString: beacon.BeaconUUID)!
            let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: CLBeaconMajorValue(beacon.BeaconMajor), minor: CLBeaconMinorValue(beacon.BeaconMinor), identifier: identifier)
            //beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
            locationManager.requestState(for: beaconRegion)
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
            locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
        }
        print(locationManager.rangedRegions)
    }
}
```

`loadBeacons` and `beaconReached` are network functions that work correctly.
The test app has location permission by the user and all the capabilities needed.

When I print the ranged regions, the beacons appear correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the life cycle of the `locationManager` object.

First, you have to define `locationManager` as a class object like this.

```
public class Kanban: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var apiKey: String!
    var userID: String!
    var beaconsJson: [BeaconItem]?

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    //...
}
```

And then, in the implementation of the framework, it must also be a class object, like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    let miniK = Kanban()
    //...
}
```